# contradicting results between discrete/continuous random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let  $(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a probability measure space, let $\lambda $ be the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb R))$, let $f: \mathscr{X} \to [0, +\infty]$ be a $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function on $\mathscr{X}$, We  can prove the following relation:

\begin{equation}
        \int_{\mathscr{X}}  f  d\mu  = \int_{[0, \infty)} \mu(\{x \in \mathscr{X}:  f(x)  > y\}) \lambda (d y)
       \end{equation}

**Proof**

Let $E$ be defined by:
    \begin{align*}
        E = \{(x,y) \in \mathscr{X} \times \mathbb R: 0 \leq y < f(x)\}
    \end{align*}
    
    In other words, $E$ is the "region under the graph $f$." Then $E$ belongs to $\mathscr{A} \times \mathscr{B}(\mathbb R)$.(This is obvious since $f$ is a measurable function).  And so its measure under $\mu \times \lambda$ can be computed using sections $E_x$ or $E^y$. On the one hand:
    \begin{equation}
        (\mu \times \lambda)(E) = \int_{\mathscr{X}} \lambda(E_x) \mu(dx) = \int_{\mathscr{X}} \big(f(x) \big) \mu(dx)
    \end{equation}
    While on the other hand: 
    \begin{equation}
        (\mu \times \lambda)(E) = \int_{\mathbb R} \mu(E^y) \lambda(dy) = \int_{[0, \infty)} \mu(\{x \in \mathscr{X}:  f(x)  > y\}) \mu(dy)
    \end{equation}
    Combining the above two equations, we get the relation: 
    \begin{align*}
        \int_{\mathscr{X}}  f  d\mu  = \int_{[0,\infty)} \mu(\{x \in \mathscr{X}:  f(x)  > y\}) \lambda(dy)
    \end{align*}

**Proof done here.**

However, if we define $E$ by \begin{align*}
        E = \{(x,y) \in \mathscr{X} \times \mathbb R: 0 \leq y \leq f(x)\}
    \end{align*}

Based on the same proof, we can have:
        \begin{equation}
        \int_{\mathscr{X}}  f  d\mu  =\int_{[0, \infty)} \mu(\{x \in \mathscr{X}:  f(x)  \geq y\}) \lambda (d y)
       \end{equation}

The main difference is that the former has strict inequality and the latter is not strict. (Note: Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ is a continuous measure has no bearing on this)

When we are dealing with a non-negative integer-valued random variable $X$, and we interpret the integral as expectation, we have the following:

$\mathbb E[X] = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P[X \geq n] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb P[X \geq n]$, which is obviously not true.

What is the logical fallacy of my process of converting integral to the discrete case?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: An atom at zero should not contribute to the expectation. It is counted in your last formula but not in the first.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Yes, but why we got this wrong equation if we strictly follow my process using integration?

Comment: Try to write the proof in the discrete case for the variable that is identically 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in the 'conversion' of the integral.

Suppose $Y$ takes values in $\{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$.
Note that as a consequence, we have $\mu[Y\ge y] = \mu[Y> y]$ except possibly for $y \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$.

For $y \in (n,n+1)$ we have
$\mu[Y\ge y] = \mu[Y> y] = \mu[Y \ge n+1]$. **Note the $n+1$ in the last expression.**

Hence we have $\int_0^\infty \mu[Y\ge y] dy = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \mu[Y\ge n+1] dy = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu[Y\ge n]$, and

$\int_0^\infty \mu[Y> y] dy = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \mu[Y > n+1] dy = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu[Y\ge n]$.

Comment: So, here since we are integrating over the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ ($dy$ in your expression), so we can delete the endpoints $\{0,1,2,3, \cdots...\}$?

Comment: That is the idea, yes.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: no idea why someone downvoted